# Getting sentences that has a certain word and store in array

Tags: php

I have a string, and I need to get all the sentences that have the word "one" in them, and store them in an array. What is the best, and fastest way to do this?

```
$text = "I have one treehouse. I have one dog. I have two cats."
```

**Needed Results**

```
$array[0] = "I have one treehouse.";
$array[1] = "I have one dog.";
```

P.S: My example code's string is kind of short, but the kind of string that I need to use this on ranges from 10-100 pages, so what is the fastest and best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Language processing gets very complicated very quickly.  Get ready for a *lot* of edge cases.

Comment: Are your sentences always in this format? Do you have something like "The one available surgeon is Dr. Smith"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a regular expression, maybe.  Something like this:

```
/[\w\s]+?\bone\s?[\w\s]*?\./g
```

In PHP, using `preg_match_all`:

```
$text = "i have one treehouse. i have one dog. I have two cats.";
$matches = preg_match_all('/[\w\s]+?\bone\s?[\w\s]*?\./', $text, $array);
```

DEMO: https://eval.in/439700

NOTE: You may need to `trim()` each of the matches, not sure if I can fix the regex to take care of that.

Comment: Can't use variables inside. For example, can't use $one instead of one.

Comment: @jessica: Inside where?  The regex?  It's just a string: `'/[\w\s]+?\b'.$one.'\s?[\w\s]*?\./'`

Comment: Exactly. You can't use that. If you do it shows an empty array instead.

Comment: @jessica: Should work fine: https://eval.in/439734.  You might need to use `preg_quote()` depending on what's in the `$one` variable.

Comment: If a sentence is something like "i'm the one!" it'll get it as "m the one!"

Comment: @jessica: I guess I'm not checking for `!` (or other non-letter) characters in the regex.  I can come back later to look at it or you can try to play around with it here: https://regex101.com/r/nW4jU9/3